# Errors using dmath for multiline equation breaking in a table with booktabs package?

Tags: tables, math-mode, equations, booktabs, breqn

I would appreciate if you can help me find a solution/way out to the following problem.

I am using the `booktabs` package to get a nice looking table.

I have  a long equation in the table which I split using the `death` environment provided by the `breqn` package (to keep the left and right parentheses' size the same).

Without using the `booktabs` package, it works as expected, but with `booktabs` the table generates many errors of the type `Missing \endgroup inserted`, `missing \cr inserted`.

My goal is to do both, equation breaking without delimiters of `\right` and `\left` problems and still use the `booktabs` package for a professionally-looking table.

Here is a sample of the code

```
\documentclass[journal,12pt,draftcls,onecolumn,a4paper]{IEEEtran}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\tn}{\tabularnewline}

\begin{document}

% This table can not be generated (many errors) when using dmath environment in conjunction with booktabs table

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}\toprule
Scheme & rule \\ \midrule
Scheme name &
\begin{dmath*}
a\left(1- \frac{1}{c!}\binom{N-1}{j-1}\sum\limits_{l=N-j}^{N-1}\binom{j-1}{N-l}(-1)^{l-N}\frac{l!}{(1+l)^{c-1}}\\
\sum\limits_{i_0,i_1,\ldots,i_{c-1}=0}^{l}\left(\prod\limits_{t=0}^{c-1}\frac{\left(\frac{1}{(1+l)t}\right)}{i_t!}\right)\left(c+\sum\limits_{t=0}^{c-1}\, i_t\right)\right)
\end{dmath*} \\ \hline
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}       
\end{table}

 %This way does work (normal table style)

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\arraybackslash}m{2.3cm}||>{\arraybackslash}m{14.3cm}|}\hline
Scheme & rule \tn[5pt] \hline
Scheme name &
\begin{dmath*}
a\left(1- \frac{1}{c!}\binom{N-1}{j-1}\sum\limits_{l=N-j}^{N-1}\binom{j-1}{N-l}(-1)^{l-N}\frac{l!}{(1+l)^{c-1}}\\
\sum\limits_{i_0,i_1,\ldots,i_{c-1}=0}^{l}\left(\prod\limits_{t=0}^{c-1}\frac{\left(\frac{1}{(1+l)t}\right)}{i_t!}\right)\left(c+\sum\limits_{t=0}^{c-1}\, i_t\right)\right)
\end{dmath*} \tn[5pt] \hline
\end{tabular}       
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I reformatted your question for better readability. You can't use `death` in an `l` column: the second one works just because you used `m` type.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to with `booktabs`.  The important thing is that the `dmath` be in a column of paragraph type, so `p{6cm}` or `m{6cm}` but not `l` or `c`.  Here is your second table with `booktab` commands and `dmath`, typeset with two different column widths, the second demonstrating the bad breaking `dmath` can make:

[image: First sample]

[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass[journal,12pt,draftcls,onecolumn,a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lm{9cm}}
  \toprule
  Scheme & Rule \\
  \midrule
  Scheme name &
  \begin{dmath*}
    a\left(1- \frac{1}{c!} \binom{N-1}{j-1} \* \sum\limits_{l=N-j}^{N-1}\binom{j-1}{N-l}(-1)^{l-N}\frac{l!}{(1+l)^{c-1}}\\
      \sum\limits_{i_0,i_1,\ldots,i_{c-1}=0}^{l}\left(\prod\limits_{t=0}^{c-1}\frac{\left(\frac{1}{(1+l)t}\right)}{i_t!}\right)\left(c+\sum\limits_{t=0}^{c-1}\, i_t\right)\right)
  \end{dmath*} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}       
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lm{6cm}}
  \toprule
  Scheme & Rule \\
  \midrule
  Scheme name &
  \begin{dmath*}
    a\left(1- \frac{1}{c!} \binom{N-1}{j-1} \* \sum\limits_{l=N-j}^{N-1}\binom{j-1}{N-l}(-1)^{l-N}\frac{l!}{(1+l)^{c-1}}\\
      \sum\limits_{i_0,i_1,\ldots,i_{c-1}=0}^{l}\left(\prod\limits_{t=0}^{c-1}\frac{\left(\frac{1}{(1+l)t}\right)}{i_t!}\right)\left(c+\sum\limits_{t=0}^{c-1}\, i_t\right)\right)
  \end{dmath*} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}       
\end{table}

\end{document}
```